# Unable to import files from a different directory in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, importerror

I am trying to import a file `profiles/first.dart` from a different directory in `main.dart` but am unable to do so for some reason. I tried both with the lower and upper case but to no avail. I am able to import other files from a different director in `profile/first.dart`.

[Here is the image where I am trying to import the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyxAz.png)

[Here is the image where I am able to import other files in `profiles/first.dart`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvgRr.png)

Comment: Does profiles folder in the lib?

Comment: Nah it wasn't but I changed it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you need to put your profile directory inside the lib directory. Looks like you have two profile directory one with upper case and another with lower case, just look at it.

Comment: It's just showing in the dropdown menu that there are two profile directories (one each w/ a different case) but there is only one profile directory. It's showing two directories for  all the other folders as well. Yeah but including the folders in the lib directory solved my problem. Thanks.